# Undo Delete Breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

Sometimes I accidentally delete a conditional breakpoint that I still wanted by misclicking on it. The following post by the Visual Studio Team suggests that it's possible to undo such a deletion in Visual Studio:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4182673-confirm-before-removing-a-breakpoint-that-has-cond

However I can't find information anywhere on how to actually do so.

Comment: try `ctrl+z` - should work I suppose

Comment: Microsoft does not treat UserVoice feature requests very seriously, it rarely goes above the "we changed everything, ought to help you too" post you saw.  Where "everything" is rarely anything more than a UI tweak, there is nothing functionally new about the VS2015 changes.  You are doing it right, this feature does not exist.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you sure about that? In their reply they say that "You can now undo/redo deleting breakpoints starting with Visual Studio 2015 Preview", which seems pretty explicit to me.

Comment: So far you have two programmers that are sure, me and you.  Not so likely you'll get more, SO users prefer happy answers

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this in Visual Studio 2017 and ctrl-Z worked to undo the delete breakpoint.  Note it seems to only do it for conditional breakpoints, it seems to ignore any intermediate removals of simple breakpoints.

Actions:

```
delete conditional breakpoint A
add simple breakpoint B
delete simple breakpoint B
ctrl-Z
```

Result: restores conditional breakpoint A

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2019, ctrl-Z does not restore simple breakpoints there either